# Showing that an improper integral defines a function over the reals.

Tags: real-analysis

For fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have the improper integral \begin{equation}\int_x^\infty e^{(x-t)^3}\ dt.\end{equation}
I want to show that this improper integral defines a function over the reals. I think I have to show that it is convergent, because then it is a function over the reals. I tried finding a majorant, but I couldn't find one...

Comment: Try to substitute $u = x-t$ in the integral.

Comment: I don't see what I can do after I do this..

Comment: See the newly posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the substitution $u=t-x$ the integral changes to $$\int _0^\infty e^{-u^3 }du$$

You can easily show that this integral is convergent.

Hint  $(0,\infty)=(0,1)\cup (1,\infty)$

Comment: Why can you state that the lower bound is 0? For me this is not easily. So, what I think is that $e^{-u^3}\leqslant 2e^{-u^2}$ for all $u>0$. And because both are locally Riemann-Integrable we have that $\int_0^\infty e^{-u^3} \leqslant \pi$. So it converges and the improper integral defines a function.

Comment: With the substitution $u=t-x$ the lower bound of $t=x$ changes to $u=0$

Comment: Okay thanks, but the rest what I stated is correct?

Comment: Yes,  your statements are correct.